# How to run Unity at startup on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: unity, 18.04

When I start `Ubuntu 18.04`, it starts with `Gnome` and gives me whithin `Gnome` the option to choose to start with `Unity`, but I want it to run with `Unity` directly from the beginning. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't select an option by means of the gear icon, then Ubuntu will start with whatever desktop was used for the last startup. Thus, once you have selected unity explicitly by means of the gear icon, it will always start unity until it is explicitly changed to something else.

Comment: If you select Unity and then make a restart, then the screen where you type in your password is gnome anyway. It only changes to unity as soon as you press enter

Comment: I'm not really sure what desktop that login screen is but does it matter? There's not much you can do at that stage, other than select a user and the desktop for the time after you've logged on.